# Docking using VCL: How to make vertically docked Forms prevail over horizontally docked Forms?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl, docking

I am using docking (VCL) in Delphi 7. In my main form, two other forms are docked: One vertically at the left edge, one horizontally at the bottom edge.

Problem: The form docked at the bottom edge takes the full width of the form, limiting the height of the form that is docked at the left edge.

I would like the opposite behaviour: The vertically docked form taking full height of the form and form docked at the bottom to be restricted in width.

That's how it looks like currently:

[image]

That's how I want it to look like:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Is this design-time or runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use panels to contain your components/forms/other panels, and build the interface from there.

In this case, put the two right-hand side forms (green and yellow) on a single panel, the green onne aligned "client", and the red one aligned "bottom" within the panel, and align the parent panel as "client". Align the red form as "left".

Comment: +1 This will result in the specific look your trying for.  Play with your bevelinner and bevelouter to get the appropriate look.

Comment: Please consider, that this is not about usual panels but docking